# Maximum RAM I can put into Asus X550JX

Tags: laptop, memory

The laptop currently has 8GB of ram. I thought I would add 4GB more into it (which is supposed to be 1600MHz DDR3) but when I opened it I found one already inside it. Is there any way to increase the ram? What can be done about this? Can I put in 8GB for example? Will the device accept 8GB extra ram. I can not find any information about particular models of laptops.

This is what I am seeing.

[image]

Comment: I have the same laptop, or an asian version of it (A550JX) same board, different model name. Anyhow the most compatible 8GB stick would probably be this one: http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-PC3L-12800-204-Pin-SoDimm-M471b1g73bh0-yk0/dp/B00J8U549K

Since it's model name is a relative match to the 4GB RAM the laptop ships with. (Note the "yk0" in the model name) has the same frequency and timing. Unfortunately the 4GB already in the machine seems to be intergrated into the board. It would take a lot of blood sweat and tears to make that into 8GBs as well to go for 16. So the max is 12.

Comment: See this http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-x550jx-extra-ram.779972/ (I bet different voltage and timings are the cause of bsods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: I used my friends 800Mhz 8GB ram and it did actually work. Task manager showed 12GB total ram. I tried to fill it up to 11GB, and I was successful. He has a spare one that I will be using soon. If any problem comes up, i'll tell here. Update about a week later: no problem as of yet

Answer (score 3):

It support up to 8G only

[Asus offical specifications Link](https://www.asus.com/tw/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550JX/specifications/) for your reference

Comment: This means 4gb that exists and 4gb extra? So nothing to be done?

Comment: Yes, but there is still some chance to override the limit. Taking S205 as example, which official state that it supported 8G ram only, but I found a  [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L3D6VL4Lno) who put 12G on it and it seems working, if you can borrow a 8GB from friends it worth to have a test, if it really can't boot then just remove it back, and it is no harm to your computer.

Comment: It's possible there's a second RAM slot hidden on the motherboard. Without a service manual or experience dismantling laptops be careful but if there are two slots you can try replacing both, like Bilo said.

Other option is that 4GB is soldered onto the motherboard and then you definitely can't upgrade it. Soldering is cheap and takes less room so more and more manufacturers are using it. In that case replace the single module that you found and hope for 12GB to work.

Either way your best bet for compatibility is picking a RAM module similar to the one already present but in the 8GB version.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and in the task manager it appears that I have 2 used slots out of 4 and that I can increase it up to 32GB

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The X550jx-xx187d has 4GB of RAM (can't be removed) and a single RAM slot.
I successfully added Corsair type CMSO8GX3M1C1600C11 and my total RAM is now 12GB, but not symmetric dual channel.

Answer (score 0):

It works on 12 GB, you can verify [here](https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/asus/laptop/x550jk). I replaced old 4GB RAM slot with Kingston 8GB DDR3 1600MHz KVR16S11/8 and it works great. As you said it has to be DDR3, 1600MHz, 1.35V and preferably CL11.